# How identify witch cpu run assembly

Tags: ida, disassembly, machine-code

I have around 300 bytes of binary machine code.

I don't know which instruction set the code is for so I can't open it with IDA.

Is there any tool that can help identify the instruction set?

Comment: Developing techniques for identification of the target architecture of object code is a challenge being actively researched. The approach used by `binwalk` is scanning for opcode signatures. See [Automatic classification of object code using machine
learning](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287615000523) as an example of a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools to identify the opcodes in a file.

1. `binwalk`

   If your blob is an archive and mix several files or has no magic numbers at the beginning, then try to run `binwalk` on it with the following options (see [binwalk's documentation](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Usage) for more details):

   ```
   #> binwalk --opcodes myfile.bin
   ```

   If you are using IDA, you can also use this [binwalk IDA plugin](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Using-the-Binwalk-IDA-Plugin).

   [image: Binwalk IDA Plugin Menu]

   [image: Result of the Binwalk IDA Plugin]
2. `file`

   If your file has some magic numbers, then the easiest way would be to run a `file` on it. This program identify a lot of different file formats and display a lot of information about each format.

   ```
   #> file myfile.bin
   ```

Comment: I don't have a bin fie,  I just have 400 bytes of hex  , I can copy it to bin file

Comment: Then, `binwalk`...

Comment: Ah, you can also use this [binwalk IDAplugin](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Using-the-Binwalk-IDA-Plugin).

Comment: what if the code is a vm code this method won't work special if it is handmade vm @perror

Comment: If you can see the bytes, then you can extract it... there is no magic here.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use [**cpu_rec**](https://github.com/airbus-seclab/cpu_rec) it claims to be able to identify a wide variety of architectures by analyzing the raw binary data ( 70 architectures).

cpu_rec is a tool that recognizes cpu instructions in an arbitrary binary file. It can be used as a standalone tool, or as a plugin for [binwalk](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk).

## How to use the tool

### As a binwalk module

Add the flag `-%` when using binwalk.

Be patient. Waiting a few minutes for the result is to be expected.
On my laptop the tool takes 25 seconds and 1 Gb of RAM
to create the signatures for 70 architectures, and then the analysis
of a binary takes one minute per Mb.
If you want the tool to be faster, you can remove some architectures,
if you know that your binary is not one of them (typically Cray or
MMIX are not found in a firmware).

### As a standalone tool

Just run the tool, with the binary file(s) to analyze as argument(s)
The tool will try to match an architecture for the whole file, and
then to detect the largest binary chunk that corresponds to a CPU
architecture; usually it is the right answer.

If the result is not satisfying, prepending twice `-v` to the arguments
makes the tool very verbose; this is helpful when adding a new
architecture to the corpus.

If https://github.com/LRGH/elfesteem is installed, then the
tool also extract the text section from ELF, PE, Mach-O or COFF
files, and outputs the architecture corresponding to this section;
the possibility of extracting the text section is also used when
building a corpus from full binary files.

Option `-d` followed by a directory dumps the corpus in that directory;
using this option one can reconstruct the default corpus.

## Examples

Running the tool as a binwalk module typically results in:

```
shell_prompt> binwalk -% corpus/PE/PPC/NTDLL.DLL corpus/MSP430/goodfet32.hex

Target File:   .../corpus/PE/PPC/NTDLL.DLL
MD5 Checksum:  d006a2a87a3596c744c5573aece81d77

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             None (size=0x5800, entropy=0.620536)
22528         0x5800          PPCel (size=0x4c800, entropy=0.737337)
335872        0x52000         None (size=0x1000, entropy=0.720493)
339968        0x53000         IA-64 (size=0x800, entropy=0.491011)
342016        0x53800         None (size=0x22000, entropy=0.727501)

Target File:   .../corpus/MSP430/goodfet32.hex
MD5 Checksum:  4b295284024e2b6a6257b720a7168b92

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             MSP430 (size=0x5200, entropy=0.472185)
20992         0x5200          None (size=0xe00, entropy=0.467086)
```

We can notice that during the analysis of `PPC/NTDLL.DLL`
a small chunk has been identified as `IA-64`.
This is an erroneous detection, due to the fact that
the IA-64 architecture has statistical properties similar
to data sections.

If the entropy value is above 0.9, it is probably encrypted or compressed
data, and therefore the result of cpu_rec should be meaningless.

Known architectures in the default corpus
[`68HC08`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_68HC08)
[`68HC11`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_68HC11)
[`8051`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51)
[`Alpha`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha)
[`ARcompact`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARC_(processor))
[`ARM64` `ARMeb` `ARMel` `ARMhf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)
[`AVR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR)
[`AxisCris`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETRAX_CRIS)
[`Blackfin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackfin)
[`Cell-SPU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(microprocessor))
[`CLIPPER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_architecture)
[`CompactRISC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactRISC)
[`Cray`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray)
[`Epiphany`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapteva)
[`FR-V`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-V_(microprocessor))
[`FR30`](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fma/pdfmcu/hm91101-cm71-10102-2e.pdf)
[`FT32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI)
[`H8-300`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H8_Family)
[`HP-Focus`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_FOCUS)
[`HP-PA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PA-RISC)
[`i860`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_i860)
[`IA-64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64)
[`IQ2000`](http://www.ic72.com/pdf_file/v/165699.pdf)
[`M32C`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/m16c.html)
[`M32R`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/m32r.html)
[`M68k`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000_series)
[`M88k`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_88000)
[`MCore`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C2%B7CORE)
[`Mico32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LatticeMico32)
[`MicroBlaze`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroBlaze)
[`MIPS16` `MIPSeb` `MIPSel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set)
[`MMIX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX)
[`MN10300`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MN103)
[`Moxie`](http://moxielogic.org/blog/)
[`MSP430`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430)
[`NDS32`](http://osdk.andestech.com/index.html)
[`NIOS-II`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nios_II)
[`OCaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml)
[`PDP-11`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11)
[`PIC10` `PIC16` `PIC18` `PIC24`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller)
[`PPCeb` `PPCel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)
[`RISC-V`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V)
[`RL78`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rl78.html)
[`ROMP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROMP)
[`RX`](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rx.html)
[`S-390`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/390_ES/9000_Enterprise_Systems_Architecture_ESA_family)
[`SPARC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC)
[`STM8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM8)
[`Stormy16`](https://sourceware.org/cgen/gen-doc/xstormy16.html)
[`SuperH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH)
[`TILEPro`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TILEPro64)
[`TLCS-90`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_TLCS#90)
[`TMS320C2x` `TMS320C6x`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS320)
[`V850`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V850)
[`VAX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX)
[`Visium`](https://www.slideshare.net/AdaCore/controls-and-dataservices)
[`WE32000`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellmac_32)
[`X86-64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)
[`X86`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)
[`Xtensa`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensilica)
[`Z80`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80)
[`#6502#cc65`](https://github.com/cc65/cc65)

Comment: This tool is unreliable due to its tendency to produce false positives. This is due in large part to a lack of binary file preprocessing required to identify and differentiate between data and code regions ("de-noising"). It is telling that in the only example given a false positive is produced.